# Exceptions return in java

Tags: java, exception

please explain the the difference between return exceptions and throw exceptions?

I see some programs use return new IOException() and the throw new IOException(). Why we use return statement, in that moment the method which included above return statement, is stop the execution?

Comment: Please show a full  example of when you've seen an exception returned rather than thrown

Answer (score 1):

> please explain the the difference between return exceptions and throw exceptions.

The difference is this:

- Throwing an exception is the normal thing to do.  It changes the flow of control.
- Returning an exception is legal, but unusual. It does not change the flow of control<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1 - ... except in the sense that *any* `return` statement does this.  The JLS talks about execution of a statement *completing normally* or *completing abruptly*.  If you want the full details, read [JLS 14.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.1).</sup>

---

However ....

```
return new SomeException(...);
```

.... is a rather dubious thing to do.  The only reasonable use-case I can think of is if your code is using these exception objects to flag multiple errors, and something else is collecting and reporting them.  You *might* do this if you needed to capture the stack traces for the locations where errors were detected.  But if not, using exceptions like this is simply ugly and inefficient.

---

> Why we use return statement, in that moment the method which included above return statement, is stop the execution?

No.  Returning an exception is no different to returning any other value.  It does not stop execution.

---

If you showed us an example of (real) application code that does this, we could have a go at explaining it.

Comment: class Demo{
 public static void main(string args[]){method();}
 public static int method(){  return 5;} 
}

if we concider about this program, it method() return the value as 5 and stop the execution of method();

class Demo{public static void main(string args[]){method();}public static IOException method(){try{return new IOException();}finally{return new IOException();}}}

But this case if we concider about first return statement, it return the IOException object and it should stop the execution of method().But the finally is run, so the execution of method() is not stopped.why this?

Comment: 1) Put your code into the question. Use the "edit" link!!  Your code is almost unreadable in a comment.  2) That is not the kind of **real** application I was asking for.  It is just a toy example. 3a) No, it shouldn't.  3b) Because that's not the way that Java works!

Answer (score 0):

Throwing exception means something is wrong and you have to try-catch the execution or it will stop the thread.

On the other hand returning an exception means nothing happened wrong. You are just creating an object (like any other objects). You still need to throw that exception object to let the program know that the exception happened.

Let's say you want an exception like `Device is not ready`. Now you can keep a method to create that exception like this,

```
public Exception getMyException() {
  return new Exception("Device is not ready yet.");
}
```

To make use of that `exception` you need to call that method and throw the exception like below,

```
public void checkFile() {
  if(...check device status is not ready ...) {
    throw getMyException();// or you could use any built-in ex like new IOException("....");
  }
}
```